# Extended Euclidean algorithm and extended remainder sequence

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

Consider the rational polynomials $h,f$:

$h:=x^8+x^6-3x^4-3x^3+8x^2+3x-5$

$f:=3x^6+5x^4-4x^2-9x+2$

Compute polynomials $r,t \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that

$r\equiv tf \mod{h}$ with $\deg r < 4, \deg t \leq 4$.

The hint is to write down the extended remainder sequence produced when executed the extended Euclidean algorithm on the input $(h,f)$ and to decide which of the triplets $(r_i,s_i,t_i)$ determine rational function approximations, i.e., a pair $(r,t)$ of polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $\deg r < n, \deg t \leq n - \deg r$ and so that

$\gcd(t,h)=1$ and $rt^{-1} \equiv f \mod{h}$

I an compute the extended Euclidean algorithm using computer algebra however I'm not sure what's meant by the "extended remainder sequence" or how to continue with this result.

Comment: I would bet extended remainder sequence means the sequence of remainders in the divisions performed while executing the extended Euclidean algorithm. Since the "extension" does not itself do any divisions, this would be the same as the sequence of remainders in the ordinary Euclidean algorithm, i.e., all the polynomials produced (probably including the two original polynomials). Maybe they mean that each remainder $r_i$ gets accompanied by its "partial Bézout coefficients" $s_i$, $t_i$ to form triples, and this is why the remainder sequence is called extended. The question suggest this.

Comment: Here I can see the sequence of remainders in the Extended Euclidean algorithm: https://mathsci2.appstate.edu/~cookwj/sage/algebra/Euclidean_algorithm-poly.html However, how can I determine the "partial Bézout coefficients" when I only know those of the gcd?